# C# and COM, IFontDisp getting converted to StdFont

Tags: c#, interface, com

I am creating a COM (User Control) in C# to be used in Excel-VBA. 
It compiles without error and I can register it on my machine.

In this COM I have the property declared like this `stdole.IFontDisp Font_Test { get; set; }`

But in the VBA, the return type automatically gets changed to `stdole.StdFont`

So in VBA it becomes `stdole.StdFont Font_Test`

Why is this automatic type conversion is happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Edit:

As per Hans's answer I checked the type library and yes it gets converted to `FONT` in C# export.

C# : Type Lib
        `[id(0x60020062), propget]
        HRESULT Font_Test([out, retval] Font** pRetVal);
        [id(0x60020062), propputref]
        HRESULT Font_Test([in] Font* pRetVal);`

OCX Type Lib:
          `[id(0xfffffe00), propget, helpstring("Returns a Font object."), helpcontext(0x000335af)]
        HRESULT Font([out, retval] IFontDisp** ppFontDisp);
        [id(0xfffffe00), propputref, helpstring("Returns a Font object."), helpcontext(0x000335af)]
        HRESULT Font([in] IFontDisp* ppFontDisp);`

Comment: IFontDisp is an *alias* in the stdole2 type library.  The .NET type library exporter applies the alias and substitutes it to `Font`.  Which is a dispinterface, VBA has no support for interfaces.  The VBA importer goes looking for a coclass that as Font as its default interface and happily finds StdFont.  You can try `IFont`, the early-bound interface name, something else should happen.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this. `IFont` also gets converted to `StdFont`. But it does expose more properties than IFontDisp. So may be a foolish question, but how come MSCOMCTL control's font properties are of type `IFontDisp` in the VBA.

Comment: You already know that answer, the .NET type library exporter was not involved with that one.