# C# COM, Set property not working as expected

Tags: c#, properties, interface, com, activex

I am creating a `C#` `COM` `ActiveX` control. Now stuck at one thing and not able to understand it.

When I create a property of the type stdole.IFontDisp, somehow the `Set` part of this property is not being invoked when the control initializes or when we try to access it from the client code. There is no error message also. It just does nothing.

Earlier this `IFontDisp` was getting converted to `stdFont` but I resolved that one by manually modifying the TypeLib/ IDL. Thanks to : [C# and COM, IFontDisp getting converted to StdFont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734975/c-sharp-and-com-ifontdisp-getting-converted-to-stdfont)

Property Implementation (C#):

```
public stdole.IFontDisp Font_Design_Time_Only
    {
       get
       {
           System.Drawing.Font fnt = new System.Drawing.Font(base.Font.Name, 
                  base.Font.Size, base.Font.Style, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
           return ActiveXCtrlHelper.GetIFontDispFromFont(base.Font);                  
       }
       set
       {
           // _stdFont = value;
           _TestFont = value;
           base.Font = this.ctrl_test.Font= ActiveXCtrlHelper.GetFontFromIFontDisp(value);
           this.ctrl_test.Invalidate();
           base.Invalidate();

       }
    }
```

IDL :

```
[id(0x60020018), propput, bindable]
HRESULT Font_Design_Time_Only([in] IFontDisp* ppFontDisp);
[id(0x60020018), propget, bindable]
HRESULT Font_Design_Time_Only([out, retval] IFontDisp** ppFontDisp);
[id(0x60020018), propputref, bindable]
HRESULT Font_Design_Time_Only([in] IFontDisp* ppFontDisp);
```

VBA:
      This code has no effect. `Set` accessor is never invoked.

```
Me.Dummy_Control.Font_Design_Time_Only.Bold = True
```

But throws no error either.

Where as the following code works and invokes the `Set` part

```
    Dim x As IFontDisp
    Set Me.Dummy_Control.Font_Design_Time_Only = x
```

Why i am getting this behavior?

Thanks, in advance.

## /#/

Update:

## /#/

IFontDisp implementation :

```
 [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(Ictrl_testEvents))]
    [Guid("C04102EB-5DE2-4CC0-9DC7-C82498FC9AFE")]
    public partial class ctrl_test : UserControl, Ictrl_test, IObjectSafety, IFontDisp{
```

//...... Other Code

```
 #region IFontDisp Impelmentation
        public bool Bold
        {
            get { return _FBold; }
            set { _FBold = value; }
        }
//rest of the implementation
```

Comment: Setting the Bold property invokes the getter, not the setter.  This isn't actually going to change your base.Font at all, the Font class does not implement this interface.  If you want to make this work then you'll have to write a [ComVisible] class that implements the IFontDisp interface so you can have your own implementation of the Bold property and detect a change.

Comment: many thanks for looking into it. I will try the `IFont` implementation tomorrow and will update.

Comment: Tried that. Both IFontDisp and IFont. No avail. :(.  Stiil, the `Set` is idle. (Updated the question with some code stub).  This Font thing is way weird in C# + COM. Will go with a property for design time and method for run time. That's the only solution I can think as of now.

Comment: VBA does not support multiple interfaces, you must declare IFontDisp to be the default interface.  Use the [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IFontDisp))] on your class.  It must be distinct class, not your control.  Pass a reference to your control through the class constructor so the property implementations know to use the control's Font.

Comment: @HansPassant, more than two years but finally got it to work. Many **thanks** for the pointers in your comment^. I am writing a datepicker activex and this is the only useful information I could find for Font implementation in C# ActiveX.